# What is git hawser?

Tags: git, git-config

I recently discovered my `.gitconfig` had been appended these few additional lines:

```
[filter "hawser"]
    clean = git hawser clean %f
    smudge = git hawser smudge %f
    required = true
```

Since it is version-controlled, I am sure I did not add them. It seems I am [not](https://github.com/dhilipsiva/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig) [the](https://github.com/CamJN/dot-files/blob/master/.gitconfig#L39-L42) [only](https://github.com/palcu/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.gitconfig#L46-L49) one to have these lines.

However: `git: 'hawser' is not a git command`. `git help` doesn't give any additional information.

So, what is this “hawser” filter?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the change in my `.gitconfig` coincided with an update to github for mac exactly, which is why I labeled it as such in my repo.

As to what Hawser actually is, Github for mac has it bundled at the `/Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/hawser/bin/git-hawser` path.

running the executable with `--help=false` yields:

```
git-hawser/0.4.0 (GitHub; darwin amd64; git 2.3.0; go 1.3)

Usage: 
  git-hawser [flags]
  git-hawser [command]

Available Commands: 
  add                       Add an entry to .gitattributes
  clean                     Implements the Git clean filter
  env                       Show the current environment
  init                      Initialize the default Git Media configuration
  logs                      View error logs
  ls-files                  Show information about hawser files
  path                      Manipulate .gitattributes
  push                      Push files to the hawser endpoint
  rm                        Remove an entry from .gitattributes
  remove                    Remove an entry from .gitattributes
  smudge                    Implements the Git smudge filter
  status                    Show information about hawser files that would be pushed
  update                    Update local hawser configuration
  version                   Show the version number
  help [command]            Help about any command

 Available Flags:
      --help=false: help for git-hawser

Use "git-hawser help [command]" for more information about that command.
```

Running `strings` on a few executables in GitHub.app turns up the string git-media|hawser which in addition to the usage message firmly indicates that git-hawser is a fork or reimplementation of git-media used to store large files outside of the git repo, as github has [a hard 100MB file size limit](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/). I'm testing now to see what happens if you try and upload a huge file through GitHub.app.

Turns out that GitHub.app doesn't use git-hawser automatically when dealing with large files, but `strings` reveals that it does have the ability to interact with a git-hawser process.

Installing the command line tools installs the `github` tool and `git-hawser` to `/usr/local/bin`. Running `git-hawser version -c` gives:

```
git-hawser/0.4.0 (GitHub; darwin amd64; git 2.3.3; go 1.3)
Nothing may see Gah Lak Tus and survive!
```

This seems related: https://github.com/blog/1986-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs

And lo, hawser filters were duplicated as lfs (large-file-support):

```
[filter "lfs"]
  clean = git lfs clean %f
  smudge = git lfs smudge %f
  required = true
```

Comment: `git media` “allows you to use Git with large media files without storing the media in Git itself.”

Comment: So we still don’t know how GitHub.app is expected to use `hawser`, but we get the intention… Thanks for the research! Would love to get the complete explanation someday  ;)

Comment: seems like they removed git-hawser in a recent update. I have a symlink at /usr/local/bin/git-hawser but my GitHub.app doesn't contain git-hawser.

Answer (score 9):

hawser is an old name for Git LFS (and git-media is the even older name), so I believe that can be dropped.

Googling this is really hard, but I finally found the commit renaming the project from hawser to lfs (https://github.com/github/git-lfs/commit/e37b69547710e2a341bc7904d291029ac594b3be), and another mentioning the old `git-media` name
(https://github.com/github/git-lfs/commit/eac36d7f04074882a7e3c9ad2cfc1d4f4a7b08fd).

So, of these blocks in ~/.gitconfig, removing the "media" and "hawser" blocks should be safe, especially once you install git-lfs. In other words, from this config blocks:

```
[filter "media"]
        required = true
        clean = git media clean %f
        smudge = git media smudge %f
[filter "hawser"]
        clean = git hawser clean %f
        smudge = git hawser smudge %f
        required = true
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        required = true
```

you can go to

```
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        required = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a consequence of installing GitHub for Mac. At least, that's the information I got from reading [this commit message](https://github.com/CamJN/dot-files/commit/8d4c713d441a7a03b398bca5d2add6beac96c416).

Answer (score -2):

Recently I have faced the same problem and I go through the site 
https://git-lfs.github.com/?utm_source=github_site&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=gitlfs

The following steps may solve your problem if you are a windows user.

1. Down load the exe for windows
2. Install it
3. 'git lfs install' run this code in git command.

Now try to push the changes.

Comment: I don't get it: the question I asked was “what is git hawser”. What is the problem you're giving a solution to?